# Слайдерный параллакс

Tags: html, parallax

**Прошу помощи в следующей задаче:** создать анимация параллакса (*поправьте, если это не он*) при перемещении курсора (*или бегунка*) от одной части экрана к другой.

**Ссылка:**https://www.instagram.com/p/B4sIafVAZts/

[image: вот так вот]

[image: вот так вот]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
let active = false;

document.querySelector('.scroller').addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
  active = true;
  document.querySelector('.scroller').classList.add('scrolling');
});

document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
  active = false;
  document.querySelector('.scroller').classList.remove('scrolling');
});
document.body.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
  active = false;
  document.querySelector('.scroller').classList.remove('scrolling');
});

document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  if (!active) return;
  let x = e.pageX;
  x -= document.querySelector('.wrapper').getBoundingClientRect().left;
  scrollIt(x);
});

function scrollIt(x) {
  let transform = Math.max(0, (Math.min(x, document.querySelector('.wrapper').offsetWidth)));
  document.querySelector('.after').style.width = transform + "px";
  document.querySelector('.scroller').style.left = transform - 25 + "px";
}

scrollIt(150);

document.querySelector('.scroller').addEventListener('touchstart', function() {
  active = true;
  document.querySelector('.scroller').classList.add('scrolling');
});
document.body.addEventListener('touchend', function() {
  active = false;
  document.querySelector('.scroller').classList.remove('scrolling');
});
document.body.addEventListener('touchcancel', function() {
  active = false;
  document.querySelector('.scroller').classList.remove('scrolling');
});
```

```css
#page {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 900px;
  height: 600px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
}

.before,
.after {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: white;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content-image {
  height: 100%;
}

.after {
  width: 125px;
}

.scroller {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: transparent;
  opacity: 0.9;
  pointer-events: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.scroller:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.scrolling {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 1;
  // z-index: 1;
}

.scroller__thumb {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.scroller:before,
.scroller:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 7px;
  height: 9999px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -3.5px;
  z-index: 30;
  transition: 0.1s;
}

.scroller:before {
  top: 100%;
}

.scroller:after {
  bottom: 100%;
}

.scroller {
  border: 5px solid #fff;
}

.scroller:before,
.scroller:after {
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="before">
      <img class="content-image" src="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1638/26145024230_06acd55d1b_b.jpg" draggable="false" /> </div>
    <div class="after">
      <img class="content-image" src="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1663/25814974803_d4c55ff708_b.jpg" draggable="false" />
    </div>
    <div class="scroller">
      <svg class="scroller__thumb" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100"><polygon points="0 50 37 68 37 32 0 50" style="fill:#fff"/><polygon points="100 50 64 32 64 68 100 50" style="fill:#fff"/></svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```